# How to select unique records from table with big number of records

Tags: postgresql

I use postgresql and I have a database table with more than 5 million records. The structure of the table is as follows:

[image]

A lot of records is inserted every day. There are many records with the same `reference`.

I want to select all records but I do not want duplicates, the records with the same reference.

I tried with query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (reference) reference_url, reference FROM daily_run_vehicle WHERE handled = False and retries < 5 ORDER BY reference DESC;
```

It executed, it gives me correct result, but it takes to long to execute.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What about an index on columns reference, handled and retries?

Comment: You mean `(handled, retries)` or `(handled, reference)`, right? Here `handled` is optional and only makes sense if the condition is selective.

Comment: There is probably no way to avoid a sort if many rows are selected. Crank up `work_mem` for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Sort keys on columns which yo used in where condition
2. after large data movement into the table, we need to do "vacuum" command it will refresh all the keys and after that Analyze the table with "Analyze" command. it will help to rebuild the stats of the table.